# What does "visudo: Warning: Cmnd_Alias `NOPASSWD' referenced but not defined," mean?

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, sudoers

I am editing the file sudoer using the visudo command. 
When I am done saving the file this warning appears.

```
visudo: Warning: Cmnd_Alias `NOPASSWD' referenced but not defined
```

I am not able to remotely execute a particular file as a non root user. I think this warning might have something to do with it.

How do I resolve this warning?

EDIT: It is actually NOPASSWD

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing your sudoers file. Mostly likely you are referencing a command 'ABCD' without the path (in some rule).

Comment: The command is NOPASSWD. It doesn't need to be defined right?

Comment: Seems like you are using the token NOPASSWD in the wrong place or wrong context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Paulo Scardine said, it is difficult to tell without looking at sudoers file.

The warning is still there but the reason I was not able to sudo remotely is because I did not put

```
Defaults !visiblepw
```

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=583911

We need to either turn it off or turn it on but we cannot do without it.